# Pictorial understanding for automorphism?

Tags: automorphism-group

I know that automorphism works by mapping an element over a some ring to another different or same element over the same ring.

How can we graphically understand automorphism?

Comment: I like to think automorphisms as shuffling the elements of my ring, that is, "switching ther names" around, in a way that it still remains the same ring. This is a heuristic of course, I would never write that down in a work.

Comment: By far the best book on this is ***Visual group theory*** by Nathan Carter.  Check that.